# How to mock directive $scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', ['$window', function($window){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {

            var w = angular.element($window);
            function adjustTop(){
                var oldtop = scope.top;
                if(oldtop<15){
                    scope.top += 2;
                }else{
                    scope.top = 0;
                }
            }

            w.bind('scroll', function () {
                adjustTop();
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I mock `scope.top` value in unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `$compile` to compile the directive and pass it with a scope where you assign the `top` attribute with. To test the changes for `scope.top` with the `scroll` event, you can make use of the JQLite's [**triggerHandler()**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) functionality.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BDGk3nQBP8GyruD4g9GM?p=preview)

**Unit Test**

```
describe('myDirective', function() {

  var element, scope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.top = 10;
    element = $compile('<div my-directive></div>')(scope);
  }));

  it('should change the scope value when scrolling', inject(function($window) {
    var jqWindow = angular.element($window);
    jqWindow.triggerHandler('scroll');
    expect(scope.top).toBe(12);
    jqWindow.triggerHandler('scroll');
    expect(scope.top).toBe(14);
    jqWindow.triggerHandler('scroll');
    expect(scope.top).toBe(16);
    jqWindow.triggerHandler('scroll');
    expect(scope.top).toBe(0);
  }));

});
```

Note: add a `scope.$apply()` within your bind event to notify angular that you have made changes in the angular's context e.g. a scope value.

```
w.bind('scroll', function () {
  adjustTop();
  scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: if the directive has no templateUrl do you need to compile an html file to get the scope?